# Pass symbols in GET variable

Tags: php

When I pass a long string along with `#`'s and `+`'s they all seem to disappear in the `$_GET` variable, how can I make them not disappear? I have tried escaping the string yet it doesn't help.

Comment: `urlencode()` is the way. http://php.net/urlencode

Answer (score 0):

Use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on your path part.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to utilize the [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) function.